# How to capture and format table data with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, database, spring, format, thymeleaf

I have a single page that contains table filled with data from database. The table is rendered via `Thymeleaf`. It contains 3 simple columns and those are: `name`, `timestamp with time zone`, `double value`.

I want to capture the values in the table and format it. Is it even possible with JS? There's no possibility to send a `GET` request to get data from the server. It has to work on the frontend side.

The double would be just divided by 1000.
The timestamp would be formated to a readable date and time and synchronized with client's time zone.

Here's the .html snippet:

```
<div class="container-fluid" style="margin-top: 20px">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table class="table table-hover ">

                        <thead class="thead-inverse">
                        <tr>
                            <th class="col-md-2 text-center">Network name</th>
                            <th class="col-md-2 text-center">Date</th>
                            <th class="col-md-2 text-center">Value</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>

                        <tr th:each="network : ${networks}" th:onclick="'javascript:openPoolModal(\''+ ${network.id} + '\');'">
                            <td class="text-center" th:text="${network.name}"> Sample data</td>
                            <td class="text-center" th:text="${network.date}">Maven Street 10, Glasgow</td>
                            <td class="text-center" th:text="${network.value}">999-999-999</td>
                        </tr>

                    </table>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Need to know your actual html to provide a solution and yes it is definitely possible to extract data from DOM using javascript.

Cheerio is for parsing and manipulating html with jquery like methods on serverside. So you can use it if you want to extract data on serverside. If you want to do this on client side, you dont need cheerio

Comment: Question edited. Html added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to give a solution without knowing how your tables and the structure may change, or how you want the data formatted, but maybe this will get you started.

```
const tds = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
for (let td of tds) {
    const data = td.textContent;
    // do something with your data
}
```

Comment: Why would my table or structure change? I do not want to interfere with the database. Just format the 2 columns as stated in the description. :) If you need any additional information, just let me know and I'll add asap.

Answer (score 0):

To populate with javascript the table tries to send the data via json, and then prints them with a loop using the "append" or "appendChild" method one by one making some transformations on a date using the "Date" function.